# pointer and which is pointed by the pointer

Tags: c, winapi, function, memory, pointers

Update : Sorry, just a big mistake. It is meaningless to write `int *a = 3;` But please just think the analogy to the case like `TCHAR *a = TEXT("text")`; (I edited my question, so some answers and comments are strange, since they are for my original question which is not suitable)

In main function, suppose I have a pointer `TCHAR *a = TEXT("text");` Then it excutes the following code:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        a = test(i);
}
```

with the function `TCHAR* test(int par)` defined by:

```
TCHAR* test(int par)
{
    TCHAR *b = TEXT("aaa");
    return b;
}
```

My question is, after executing the above code, but before the program ends, in the memory:

```
    1. the pointer `a` remains?
    2. The 1000 pointers `b` are deleted each time the function test(...) exits ?
    3. But there are still 1000 memory blocks there?
```

---

In fact, my question is motivated from the following code, which shows a tooltip when mouse is over a tab item in a tab control with the style TCS_TOOLTIPS:

```
case WM_NOTIFY
    if (lpnmhdr->code == TTN_GETDISPINFO) {
    LPNMTTDISPINFO lpnmtdi;
    lpnmtdi = (LPNMTTDISPINFO)lParam;

    int tabIndex = (int) wParam; // wParam is the index of the tab item.

            lpnmtdi->lpszText = SetTabToolTipText(panel->gWin.At(tabIndex));
            break;
    }
```

I am thinking if the memory usage increases each time it calls

`SetTabToolTipText(panel->gWin.At(tabIndex))`, which manipulates with `TCHAR` and `TCHAR*` and return a value of type `LPTSTR`.

Comment: Sorry, it just a typo. test() return a pointer to int.

Comment: What are the definitions of TCHAR and TEXT? And your questions are very confused. a and b are just names; they aren't "deleted", they go out of scope. There are no "memory blocks", there is just the one string literal "aaa", which gets returned from test every time (assuming TEXT is just a noop or a cast).

Comment: And the code you posted is horribly formatted and not syntactically correct; post real code and indent it properly. As for whether SetTabToolTipText allocates memory, you need to read its specification.

Comment: @Jim, my question is just that if each time I use the string "aaa", it will allocate memory. If you can point why the code is horribly formatted, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, the pointer a remains till we return from the main function
2. The variable b (a 4-byte pointer) is automatic. It is created each time we call test function. Once we return from it, the variable disappears (the pointer). Please note, the value to which b points isn't affected.
3. No. In most of the cases, I think, there will be only one block allocated during compilation time (most likely in the read-only memory) and the function will be returning the same pointer on every invocation.

If `SetTabToolTipText` allocates a string inside using some memory management facilities new/malloc or some os-specific, you should do an additional cleanup. Otherwise there'll be a memory leak.

If nothing like this happens inside (it's not mentioned in the documentation or comments etc), it's most likely returning the pointer to some internal buffer which you typically use as readonly. In this case, there should be no concerns about a memory consumption increase.

Comment: @ Negai: In SetTabToolTipText, how happens if I use `TCHAR *b = TEXT("text")` and `return b`? I think I should do some cleanup in this case, right?

Comment: No, not really. Usually compilers put the string "text" to a read-only data segment and whenever you have TEXT("text") in your code, this simply means you are getting a pointer to that region that is reserved in the program during the compilation time. Thus, no cleanup is required - the "text" is already in the generated binary file.

Answer (score 2):

You dont allocate any memory so you don't have to worry about memory being freed. When your vaiables go out of scope they will be freed automatically. In this function

```
 int test(int par)
 {
    int *b = par;
 }
```

you don't have a return value even though the function says that is will return an `int`, so you should probably do so as in this line

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    a = test(i);
}
```

you assign to `a` the value that is returned by `test()`. Also

```
int* a = 3;
int* b = par;
```

are asking for trouble. You are assigning integer values to a pointer variable. You should probably rethink your above code.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer should contain adress... so `int* a = 3` is something meaningless... And in function you don't allocate memory for int (only for par variable, which then destroy when the function ends), you allocate memory for storing adress in `int* b`, this memory also free when the funciton ends.